# Regularity of the parabolic equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the initial boundary value problem of the parabolic problem:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\Delta u&=f(x,t), \\
u|_{\partial p Q_T}&=0,
\end{align}
on $Q_T=\Omega\times(0,T)$. We let the boundary be smooth enough.

Now there is a thm 1 claim that: if $f\in L^2(Q_T),u\in \dot{W}^{1,1}_2$ is a weak solution, then
$u\in W^{2,1}_2(Q_T)$ besides, we have estimate:$||u||_{ W^{2,1}_2(Q_T)}\leq C||f||_{L^2(Q_T)}$. Based on this thm 1, there is another thm 2 says: when $u\in \dot{W}^{1,1}_2$ is a weak solution, $f\in W_2^{2k,k}(Q_T)$, then $u\in W^{2k+2,k+1}_2(Q_T)$.

$\dot{W}^{m,k}_2$ means the closure of $\dot{C^\infty}(\overline{Q_T})$ in $W^{m,k}_2$,$\dot{C^\infty}(\overline{Q_T})$ is consist by the function that take 0 on $\partial p Q_T$ and infinitely differentiable.

Now, I encountered difficulties in improving the regularity of t-direction, should I consider another way to define weak solution?

Besides, why is the exponent of Sobolev space of $f$ in condition must be $2k,k$, how is it going when $f\in W^{m,k}_2(Q_T)$? Could we get $u\in W^{m+2,k+1}_2(Q_T)$ in this circumstance by using change $u_x=v,u_t=v$ directly?

Comment: An unreasonable point is the definition of weak solution in my textbook. $\iint_{Q_T}(u_t\phi+\nabla u\cdot\nabla\phi)dxdt=\iint_{Q_T}f\phi dxdt$ where $\phi$ is test function. It demands the differentiable of $t$ direction of $u$. When we substitute $u$ by $u_t$, it appears $u_{tt}$！